# Getting status information of check_mysql-health command in Nagios Core

Tags: nagios, server-monitoring

Am using the NagiosQL to configure the Nagios core, i have a problem with check_mysql_health plugin it is not returning status information in Nagios core but if run same command in command-line it is gives the proper result. Can anyone suggest me some solution for this?

Thanks
Somesh

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution for my problem, to get the status information in Nagios core we have to set the path of the check_mysql_health plugin in 4 different config files /etc/nagios/command-plugin.cfg - add the plugin path,/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg - add the plugin path, /etc/nagiosql/commands.cfg - add the plugin path at command definition, /etc/nagios/objects/commands.cfg - define the command for check_mysql_health, and the Additional templates must be a generic templates in service panel of NagiosQL